# Cannot connect my android studio with Database

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I'am lost, I want to connect my android studio with java to database jdbc, but I don't know how. I tried this code, and it doesn't work. I use Java, and I have Uwamp Server with PHPmyAdmin.
I look on forum, and I see people who say it's possible, others say it's not, I really don't know what to do.
I took this code from a forum.

```
package com.example.luddiagappli;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/luddiag";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
             Log.d("success", "caca");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InfoAsyncTask", "Error reading school information", e);
        }


    }
}
```

Exception stack trace:

```
//error
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/luddiag
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:605)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
        at com.example.luddiagappli.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android (and recent versions are may not even work due to using features not available on Android).

Answer (score 0):

You must load driver first.

```
  String driverName = "org.mysql.jdbc.driver"; // your driver name 
  Class.forName(driverName);
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work, plus it's not necessary now.

Comment: Explicitly loading the driver - at least in Java, not sure about Android - is usually not necessary when using a JDBC 4 compliant driver (JDBC 4 was introduced with Java 6, back in 2006).